# What is the cohomology of the $C^{\infty}$-Koszul complex on $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, homological-algebra

First we consider the holomorphic Koszul complex on $\mathbb{C}^2$:
$$
0\to \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C}^2)\overset{\begin{pmatrix}-z_2\\z_1\end{pmatrix}}{\to} \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C}^2)^{\oplus 2}\overset{(z_1,z_2)}{\to} \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{C}^2)\to \mathbb{C}\to 0.
$$
It is well-known that the above complex is exact.

Now we consider the $C^{\infty}$-version of the Koszul complex
$$
0\to C^{\infty}(\mathbb{C}^2)\overset{\begin{pmatrix}-z_2\\z_1\end{pmatrix}}{\to} C^{\infty}(\mathbb{C}^2)^{\oplus 2}\overset{(z_1,z_2)}{\to} C^{\infty}(\mathbb{C}^2)\to \mathbb{C}\to 0.
$$
It is clear that the above complex is not exact. For example $\bar{z_1}$ and $\bar{z_2}$ both vanish at the origin but are not in the image of multiplying $z_1$ and $z_2$.

> > My question is: What is the cohomology of the above complex?

Comment: As far as you are concerned there is no difference between $\mathbb{C}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^4$. In both cases you would be calculating the complex valued functions on them and evaluating at the origin. Hence, the correct Koszul complex to compare with is the one for $\mathbb{R}^4$. This observation would probably give you the answer to your question.

Comment: Indeed, @Kapil is absolutely right. Forget for a second about the rightmost term $\mathbb{C}$ (which is usually not included in the Koszul complex anyway). Then your second complex is obtained from your first complex by extending the ground ring from $\mathbb{C}$ to the ring of antiholomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}^2$, which immediately shows that its homology is the latter ring.

Answer (score 1):

As Vladimir mentions in the comment, it is probably easier to formulate this without the $\mathbb{C}$ at the right. However, it is not clear to me that the answer then is exactly what Vladimir claims, i.e., that you get the antiholomorphic functions as cohomology at level $0$.

I am not sure if you intend the statement to be for global sections, as I interpret your notation, but since the involved sheaves $\mathbb{C}$ and $C^\infty$ are acyclic on $\mathbb{C}^2$, and the complexes are exact outside the origin, you might just as well consider the corresponding complexes of stalks at the origin.

By [flatness of the smooth functions over the holomorphic functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226136/is-the-sheaf-of-smooth-functions-flat), it follows that you have an exact complex of sheaves
$$0 \to C^\infty_0 \to (C^\infty_0)^{\oplus 2} \to C^\infty_0 \to C^\infty_0/((z_1,z_2)C^\infty_0) \to 0,$$
where $C^\infty_0$ denote the ring of germs of smooth functions at $0$.

The map from the antiholomorphic functions, $\overline{\mathcal{O}_0} \to C^\infty_0/((z_1,z_2)C^\infty_0)$ is injective, since $\overline{\mathcal{O}_0} \cap (z_1,z_2)C^\infty_0 = \\{0\\}$ (which you might verify by reducing to the one-dimensional case, by restricting to complex lines to the origin). However, it is not so clear to me that the map is actually surjective.

Comment: What is the answer for the real version? For example, let $R$ be the local ring of smooth functions at $(\mathbb R^2,0)$, and $A$ the local ring of real analytic functions there. The Koszul complex $\DeclareMathOperator\Kos{Kos}\Kos(R;x,y)$ is quasi-isomorphic to the derived tensor product $R\otimes_A^L\mathbb R$, which is the usual tensor product by flatness, but this seems to be complicated?

Comment: It should follow rather easily from appropriate versions of Taylors formula that the cohomology is just $\mathbb R$ at level $0$. More precisely, at level $0$, it should follow from the fact that any smooth function $f$ may be written as $f(x,y) = f(0,0) + xf_1(x,y)+yf_2(x,y)$ for appropriate smooth functions $f_1,f_2$, and to see that the cohomology vanishes at level $1$, one should be able to use that any smooth function $g(x,y)$ may be written as $g(x,y) = g_1(y) + x g_2(x,y)$ for appropriate smooth functions $g_1,g_2$.

Comment: Thanks. This is called [Hadamard's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_lemma). I forgot this. This vanishing seems also a bit similar to Poincaré's lemma.